# Need some JavaScript explanation for this code

Tags: javascript

I know that it is bad practice to write code like this:

```
var createBox = function(width, height, margin){
    alert("Margin is set to " + margin);
    //margin is undefined in this context or why?
    var margin = margin || 2;
    alert("Margin is now " + margin);
}
createBox(0,0,0);
```

But can someone please explain, why margin is always set to 2?

Is it because it is undefined in the direct context of initializing a variable with the same name inside the function?

edit: sorry, I got the problem wrong ...

Please give a small hint :)
Regards, Tom

Comment: Thanks for editing, forgot to post the code :)

Comment: It is not possible that your second example alerts 0.  Put it on jsbin or jsfiddle and show us if you really think that's what happens, but it won't happen. (Are you sure that you didn't leave "margin" in the second alert instead of "margin2"?)

Comment: **Lies!** Easy explanation: the second code also alerts `2`: http://jsbin.com/erehu3

Comment: What exactly is "as expected" in your case?

Comment: I was wrong, my fault. Did see some js-ghosts or something ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `||` operator in JavaScript returns the value of the first operand if the first operand is truthy. Otherwise it returns the value of the second operand. It doesn't return `1`/`0`, or `true`/`false`, as in some other languages.

Therefore when the `margin` argument holds a falsy value, such as `0` or `undefined`, it will return `2`, since these are both falsy values in JavaScript.

The falsy values in JavaScript are: an empty string `""`, the `null` value, a value of `0`, the `NaN` value, the boolean value `false`, and also `undefined`.

What you describe is a very common idiom in JavaScript. In fact the `||` operator is sometimes called *the default operator*<sup>1</sup>. You can use it to assign default values to variables when they are `undefined`. The problem in this case is that since `0` is a valid argument, the *default operator* is not behaving as required. You may want to do the following instead:

```
margin = typeof margin === 'undefined' ? 2 : margin;
```

---

<sup>1</sup> [Douglas Crockford: The Elements of JavaScript Style - Part 2 - Idioms.](http://javascript.crockford.com/style2.html)

Comment: Yes Daniel, but why is margin undefined? if I use f.e. var margin2 = margin || false; margin2 is set to 0 as expected

Comment: @shapeshifta: Updated my answer... `margin` is not undefined. It is set to `0`, which is also a "falsy" in JavaScript. Therefore, the `||` operator returns the second operand: `2` and assigns it to `margin`.

Comment: I think you are right in a way, but that is not the answer for my problem I think. Just compare: var margin = margin || 2 //2; var margin2 = margin || 2; //0 -> this is my question :)

Comment: @shapeshifta it is the answer to your problem.

Comment: to much coffee, to little sleep ... sorry!

Answer (score 3):

If you call createBox(0,0,0), then margin is 0 (which has the truth value of `false`), so the expression `margin || 2` becomes `0 || 2` which is equal to 2.

Comment: but if I write var margin2 = margin || 2, margin2 is set to 0 as expected ;)

Comment: @shapeshifta no it is not set to 2. That definitely will not happen if margin is zero.

Comment: Not for me. `margin2` outputs 2 on the last alert.

Comment: Oh I am so sorry, I mixed it up ... :(

Answer (score 2):

0 evaluates to false [List of Truthy Values](http://www.isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/TruthyFalsyAndTypeCasting)

Answer (score 1):

```
// This function creates a new box by receiving three parameters
var createBox = function(width, height, margin){
    // Output the margin of the box, zero in current case
    alert("Margin is set to " + margin);
    // If the margin is zero or undefined, '' set default value to 2
    var margin = margin || 2;
    // Output the new value of the margin which is 2
    alert("Margin is now " + margin);
}
// here will show Margin: 0 after that Margin: 2
createBox(0,0,0);

// here will show Margin: 1 after that Margin: 1
createBox(0,0,1);

// here will show Margin: 3 after that Margin: 3
createBox(1,2,3);
```